# IE-only mouse event issue when mouse button held down

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

The following jQuery code is being used to display tooltips on various form textbox (`input type='text' title='tooltip text'`) elements. It works, apart from in one specific scenario, in IE (7-9) only.

```
function toolTip() {
    var xOffset = 10;
    var yOffset = 20;

    $(".tooltip")
        .each(function () {
            this.tooltipText = this.title;
            $(this).removeAttr("title");
        })
        .mouseenter(function (e) {
            $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.tooltipText + "</p>");
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
        })
        .mouseleave(function () {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
        })
        .mousemove(function (e) {
            $("#tooltip")
                .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
        });
}
```

That scenario is as follows:

- Mousedown in a textbox
- Move the mouse out of the text box *tooltip continues to display*
- Release the mouse button *tooltip stays visible after the mouse button is released*

The problem is caused by various mouse events firing when the mouse is moved over other elements, *apart from* a final `mouseleave` when the mouse button is released. See a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/richev/VXUS9/8/. Any thoughts on what's going on here?

### Update

This issue also exists in IE on the [Bassistance jQuery tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/).

Comment: could try using `mousedown` on the input to remove tip ...likely better user experience anyway as tooltip won't be visible while they try to edit

Comment: @charlietfl Sadly that does not solve the issue, because a new `mouseenter` event fires when the mouse goes over another HTML element.

Comment: I meant use both events... the current mouseleave works when no click on input but also add mousedown

Comment: The mouseleave event is in fact firing: http://jsfiddle.net/BS3EF/1/ The problem is that the mouseenter event fires several times thereafter.

Comment: @Asad Is very strange though in IE..with mouse button down, mouseenter and mouseleave fire repeatedly  http://jsfiddle.net/VXUS9/16/ It's not a persistence issue, the tooltip is being recreated ....wierd

Comment: @Asad I have updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interim solution while you figure out mouseevents. Basically it checks whether the target is in fact the input before executing the mouseenter code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LCefq/1/

```
function toolTip() {
    var xOffset = 10;
    var yOffset = 20;

    var tooltipElems = $(".tooltip");

    tooltipElems.each(function() {
        this.tooltipText = this.title;
        $(this).removeAttr("title");
    });

    tooltipElems.mouseenter(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('.tooltip')) {
            $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>" + this.tooltipText + "</p>");
            $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
            $('#state').append("<div>mouseenter" + $(e.target)[0].tagName +"</div>");
        }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("#tooltip").remove();
        $('#state').append("<div>mouseleave</div>");
    });

    $(".tooltip").mousemove(function(e) {
        $("#tooltip").css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    toolTip();
});
```

My results from the following [test](http://jsfiddle.net/LCefq/2/) (IE8) look like this, although evidently you are getting different results.

[image]

Comment: The issue still exists in this approach I'm afraid @Asad, because `$(e.target).is('.tooltip')` even when the mouse has left the textbox.

Comment: @RichardEv No it isn't. Did you try the fiddle? I tested this in IE9 and it works (it was broken before).

Comment: I did. I see `mouseleave` and `mouseenterINPUT` in the `state` div even as I mouseover the two `p` elements, when I mousedown in the textbox and then move the mouse around.

Comment: @RichardEv That's weird, it works correctly in 9 (and 8). What are you using?

Comment: @RichardEv See this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/LCefq/2/. When you mousedown over the input and move around outside, the logged `target`s are `BODY`, `HR`, `DIV`, `P` etc. not `INPUT` (unless of course you move over the input)

Comment: @RichardEv Sorry for the triple post, but when you say: `I see mouseleave and mouseenterINPUT in the state div even as I mouseover the two p elements, when I mousedown in the textbox and then move the mouse around.` That is *supposed* to happen, but only once. If you see it happening repeatedly when moving between paragraphs (while avoiding the input) there's a problem.

Comment: I'm on IE9 (version 9.0.8112.16421, update versions 9.0.10), Windows 7.

Comment: @RichardEv Could you please tell me what you see in the fiddle I posted in my comment?

Comment: Unfortunately I see the same issue I originally reported. `mouseleave` and `mouseenterINPUT` repeatedly as I mouseover the `p` elements.

Comment: I still see the same issue I'm afraid, even with your latest version. The diagram you added to your post correctly represents the action I am performing to cause the problem. My results however are different...